# Bug Report XSLTForms Range Control?

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

The range control in my XForm is not binding the input value to the model. That is I enter a value but the field the control is bound to in the model does not update.

I have tried a couple of public domain examples

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Bind_to_ranges
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Range

In both these examples the range control is set but frozen (i.e you cannot move it). If you remove the initialising values from the model the form does not display to completion.

Can somebody verify the status of the range control functionality in XSLTForms 1.1 R649.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, the range control was an experimental feature in XSLTForms a long time ago and, because authors did not report any need for it, it has not been tested with recent browsers.

As far as I remember, two explicit limits are required. Do you have your own minimal test case?

I will take a look as soon as possible.

Comment: The  code in the links I posted are both suitable test cases.